# Is there a way to create "public" .dll variables?

Tags: c#, powershell, registry, regedit

I am currently working on a Windows 10 version, where I'm doing performance tweaks and set it up.
Since I'd like to publish it, I want to add multi-language support.

I have added a right-click context menu item where you can "open powershell window here as administrator". 
There is the default "open powershell window here" which doesn't use a hardcoded value as displayName, it's kind of accessing a variable in the "shell32.dll" (see screenshot).

[image: take a look at the (Default) value/ data]

And because this is not a hardcoded value, it gets the correct language text from the .dll (where the names are hardcoded.)

I would like to create my own .dll with different texts for different languages. I would create the .dll in C#, since I only know C# and it shouldn't be a problem. Let's use my idea from above.
I don't want to use a hardcoded English text with "Open PowerShell window here as administrator". I want that it uses the correct PC language.

I don't exactly know how the .dll looks like, but this is the concept: 
en-GB: "English text", de-DE: "German text". Then name the .dll like "languageText.dll" and "call" the text variable just like it is done for normal powershell (from the screenshot) e.g.: @languageText.dll,-1

So at the end it will show "English text" when System Language is English (en-GB) and "German text" when it is German (de-DE).

Comment: Any class that you declare `public` in a dll will be public to calling code. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: I want to "call"/ get the variable outside of the code (to be more exact, in windows' registry)

Comment: Call must be from a script or program. Are you calling from Powershell or another C# program?

Comment: I'm not doing anything.
As you can see in the screenshot which is from the windows 10 registry, windows is accessing a value that is stored in the @shell32.dll. And I want to do that by myself, create a .dll and then access a value that is in the .dll from the registry. Just like it's done in the screenshot

Comment: `shell32.dll` is a core component of Windows and PowerShell. AFAIK there's no way to replace it's functionality.

Comment: that's the question I'd like to get: Is it possible to "replicate" this feature/ functionality. (to achive the same with your own .dll).
Thanks for you answer, maybe someone knows, if it's possible :)

Comment: You should read on Win32 Windows resources and see how particular type you are looking for can be added to C# assembly. Should be relatively straight forward after you figure out what exact type of resource you need to add. Some of them are supported directly, some may need using native Windows tools. See if https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/resources/creating-resource-files-for-desktop-apps and links from it help to clarify what you want.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov but I don't want to access something from my C# app.
The article you sent, is about accessing text from a text file in your C# app